# How to create Objects array or Classes array in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object

**How to create Objects array or Classes array in C++?**

I mean,How to make it so that you do not create objects manually like here:

```
Prozessor Obj1;
Prozessor Obj2;
```

I mean, that I don't want to create 10 objects manually.
But by a cycle `for` or `while`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Prozessor
{
  private:
  char marka[20];
  float chastota;  
  float cash;
  float vartist;

  public:

  void setProzessor()
    {
        cout << "Input brand: ";
        cin >> marka;
        cout << "Input chastotu : ";
        cin >> chastota;
        cout<<"Input number of cash:";
        cin>>cash;
        cout<<"Input vartist:";
        cin>>vartist;
    }
  void showProzessor()
  {
    cout << marka << " " << chastota <<" "<< cash << " " << vartist <<endl;

  }
};

int main()
{
   Prozessor Obj1;
   Prozessor Obj2;
   cout<<"vvedit dani"<<endl;
   Obj1.setProzessor();
   Obj2.setProzessor();

   Obj1.showProzessor();
   Obj2.showProzessor();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can declare arrays in the same way you doit with struct or default  types

```
struct Point { };
class Prozessor { };

int main()
{
    // an array of ints
    int arrint[10];
    // an array of Points
    Point arrPoint[10];
    // an array of Objects of the class Prozessor
    Prozessor arrProzessor[10];

    return 0;
}
```

---

nowadays we have more options to do that

[vector](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is one that allows you to manage set of data without previously knowing the size of the container

```
std::vector<Prozessor> vectorOfProzessors;
```

Comment: Correct, but `std::vector` and `std::array` are better choices.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `std::vector` or `std::array` depending on if you know the size at compile time.

```
std::vector<Prozessor> prozessors;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    Prozessor prozessor;
    prozessor.SetProzessor();
    prozessors.push_back(prozessor);
}
```

Comment: IMO a note about the constructor (being able to default-construct elements) and maybe `emplace_back` would be helpful

Comment: Thanks, how to do that by array, like structure array?